# Split an array into multiple arrays by empty string - Typescript

Tags: arrays, typescript

How can I split an array into multiple arrays and store each of these new arrays as their own variable?

Example

```
  let arr: string[] = [
"",
"Names",
"jack",
"paul",
"sarah",
"",
"Genders",
"m",
"m",
"m",
"f",
"",
"Cars",
"range rover",
"bmw",
"mercedes",
"dodge",
];
```

How can I split this array with TypeScript to new arrays like (before every new variable there is an empty string in the array (before Names, Genders and Cars):

```
names: string[] = ["Names", "jack", "paul", "sarah",]

genders: string[] = ["m","m","m","f"]

cars: string[] = ["Cars", "range rover", "bmw", "mercedes", "dodge",]
```

Comment: Note that your `genders` array seems to be missing the initial `"Genders"` element; I'm assuming that's a typo.

Comment: Also I assume you're okay if the output of your transformation results in an array-of-arrays and you need to copy each one to a variable of your choosing, since there's no great way to programmatically generate variable names from strings.

Comment: Yes that is typo

Answer (score 0):

You can use [the `reduce()` array method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) to walk through `arr` and *accumulate* your output array of arrays of strings:

```
const result = arr.reduce<string[][]>(
    (a, s) => !s ? [...a, []] : [...a.slice(0, -1), [...a[a.length - 1], s]]
    , []);
```

In the above, `a` is the *accumulator* which stores the output so far, and `s` is the current string element from `arr`.   The idea is that `s` is an empty string you add a new empty array to the end of `a`, and when `s` is non-empty you put it at the end of the last array in `s`.

I've gone the route of treating everything as immutable, using [the `slice()` array method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice) and [destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) and [array spread](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) to manipulate arrays.  The value `[...a, []]` has the same elements as `a` with a new empty array at the end.  The value `[...a.slice(0, -1), [...a[a.length - 1], s]]` has the same elements as `a` except the last one has `s` added to the end.  (`a.slice(0, -1)` uses [the `slice()` array method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice) to get a copy of `a` without the last element, and `a[a.length-1]` is that last element.)

Let's test it:

```
console.log(result);
/* [["Names", "jack", "paul", "sarah"], 
    ["Genders", "m", "m", "m", "f"], 
    ["Cars", "range rover", "bmw", "mercedes", "dodge"]]*/
```

Looks good, and you can assign those arrays to separate variables if you want:

```
const [names, genders, cars] = result;

console.log({ names, genders, cars });
/* {
  "names": [
    "Names",
    "jack",
    "paul",
    "sarah"
  ],
  "genders": [
    "Genders",
    "m",
    "m",
    "m",
    "f"
  ],
  "cars": [
    "Cars",
    "range rover",
    "bmw",
    "mercedes",
    "dodge"
  ]
} */
```

Looks like what you wanted.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#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-DAgqFwpyojDA1ReYkMxA8KRrRBBUA)

Comment: Just want to raise a question in your brain what if the array contains different data? I mean it will have different data instead of names, cars, and genders also what if the main array has the data which we can able to make 10 sub-arrays from it

Comment: I just edited to show that the output of `reduce()` here is an array of arrays (and you can then assign these arrays to different variables if you want).  If you have different data with ten blank strings in it then you will get an array of ten arrays.

Comment: Dividing the array into sub-arrays is ok but creating dynamic subarrays variables is a bit challenging.

Comment: Sadly I get an error: a[(a.length - 1)] is not iterable

Comment: Can you share what input gives that error?  In my answer there’s a playground link where you can run my code and see that it works. Is there an error in that code? Or is in some other input? I’m happy to help but I need more information.

Comment: My *guess* is that you are running on a set of strings that does not start with an empty string.  So your example code above looks like `["", "foo", "bar", "", "baz", "qux"]` but maybe you're running it against something like `["foo", "bar", "", "baz", "qux"]`.  Is that what's going on?  If you need to support that then you should [edit] the question to demonstrate your needs with a [mre].  That's just a guess though so I hope you'll get back to me.

Answer (score -1):

Use JS Object for storing this kind of data structure:

```
type myObject = {
   "Names": ["jack", "paul", "sarah"],
   "Genders": ["m","m","m","f"],
   "Cars": ["range rover", "bmw", "mercedes", "dodge"]
}
```

then you access like this:

```
myObject.Names => ["jack", "paul", "sarah"]
```

Comment: Problem is that this data is fetched from the csv, so i get an array like in the example but with different data. Same structure

Comment: then you should write that